# What was Jeremy Corbyn’s involvement in the Northern Ireland peace process?

Tags: united-kingdom, northern-ireland, ireland, jeremy-corbyn

I’ve heard mixed reports as to his involvement; some reports describe him as a broker of peace whose efforts brought an early end to the Troubles, while others describe him as a terrorist sympathizer who repeatedly met with and supported militants from the IRA.

Is it possible to put aside opinion as much as is sensible and give an objective account of his involvement?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no evidence that Corbyn advocates terrorism or other kinds of violence and he has consistently stated his opposition to violence. If "sympathise" means agree, approve, favourable to, support, Corbyn did openly "sympathise" with the IRA's ultimate goal of a united republican Ireland, but he does not appear to "sympathise" with violence. Corbyn's position is that he wanted to aid the peace process (we can only speculate about his contribution).

But a public relations challenge for Corbyn is that he has historically behaved so as to provide many opportunities to be portrayed as a "terrorist sympathiser" - and not just in relation to the IRA but with Hamas and Hezbollah too. He has also appeared to deny or refuse to acknowledge their terrorist acts. There are patterns of behaviour since his public life began.

It is unclear whether he understands that or is bothered by it but it is clear that many won't forgive him for it.

Corbyn has repeatedly avoided unequivocally condemning IRA violence when asked, choosing instead to condemn the violence on both sides or all bombing, and attended meetings with and vigils for people associated with terrorism. He has referred to these people as "friends", "honoured citizens" and such, rather than neutral terms.

Corbyn met with Sinn Féin's leader Gerry Adams several times during The Troubles in the 1980s. Sinn Féin (rightly or wrongly) considered the political wing of the IRA with interchangable membership and Gerry Adams was alleged (he denies it) to be part of the IRA's leadership - at the very least having some influence. Such meetings were very controversial in that period.

Two weeks after [the IRA's Brighton hotel bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brighton_hotel_bombing) intended to assassinate the Conservative party's leadership, including then Prime Minister Margaret Thatcher, and which killed five people and injured over 30, Corbyn invited Gerry Adams and convicted terrorists Linda Quigley and Gerry MacLochlainn to the House of Commons.

Labour's then Chief Whip Michael Corks [commented](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ED7ko98X4AIdob_.jpg),

> in the present climate of opinion this action must be regarded as
>   thoughtlessness of the highest order.

Labour's leader Neil Kinnock was said to be [appalled](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DVXVcktXkAAkb5Z.jpg:large) and furious.

The meeting was also shortly before the first anniversary of the 1983 Harrods bombing, which killed six people and injured 90.

Corks told the BBC,

> I think that, unless you are very very careful, any contact with
>   people of this sort gives credence to their cause, and unless you are
>   very careful that can lead to people thinking you are actually
>   indifferent to the outrage, the suffering, the killing and the maiming
>   which is the direct consequence of the actions of people who are
>   terrorists.

Corbyn was unrepentant and said he'd do it again. Gerry MacLochlainn claimed to have visited Parliament several times, as a constituent of Corbyn's, and he was reportedly a regular at Corbyn's constituency office. Corbyn denies meeting anyone in the IRA.

Two months later, [the Guardian wrote of Corbyn](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ED7lS9pWwAAuBZi.jpg):

> Mr Corbyn and a sizeable number of other left Labour MPs ... will
>   continue their sordid romantic infatuation with the Provisional IRA.
>
> Mr Corbyn's invitation to two convicted terrorists to meet him in the Commons in
>   October can be attacked on several grounds. It was a very stupid
>   political gesture from someone who is an elected member of a party
>   opposed to terrorism. It was appallingly timed, so soon after the
>   Brighton hotel bombing. ... We agree with Mr Ivor Stanbrook, the very
>   right-wing Conservative MP for Orpington, when he says that to stop
>   the public from meeting their MPs is to play into the hands of
>   democracy's enemies. But there is a time and a place for everything
>   and Mr Corbyn has little reason to feel proud of his judgment.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I'm pretty sure there's been plenty of scrutiny toward's Labour's issues with anti-semitism, I'd be hard pressed to find a month in the last 3 years where it hasn't been a front page story at least once. Similarly Corbyn's links to the IRA and Hamas are frequently mentioned.

Comment: "Sinn Féin (rightly or wrongly) considered the political wing of the IRA" [The Provisional IRA and Sinn Fein have always been commanded by the Provisional Army Council.  Thus PIRA/Sinn Fein are different sides of the same coin.  To say anything else would be counter-factual.](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/469548/Paramilitary_Groups_in_Northern_Ireland_-_20_Oct_2015.pdf).

Comment: Also Gerry Adams [was a senior leader of the PIRA](https://www.belfasttelegraph.co.uk/news/northern-ireland/ive-no-regrets-about-gerry-adams-ira-claim-says-republican-38508667.html).  So you have to keep the structure of the PIRA and the reality of who was leading it in mind when considering Corbyn's relationship with Republican politics.  As you point out, it raises many question.  But at this point there is sufficient evidence that the PIRA and Sinn Fein were and still are tightly coupled entities.

Comment: @inappropriateCode the shared leadership and organisational entanglement may be beyond dispute, but I think the character of the relationship between the two entities is a matter of some mystery and dispute. Sinn Féin being the political wing of the IRA is one characterisation that draws the sharpest criticism of Corbyn's actions, so relevant here, but I don't think it's a settled straightforward fact that the relationship was this way round as opposed to the IRA being the paramilitary wing of Sinn Féin or a shared leadership having inabsolute control over both organisations.

Comment: Worth noting that Adams was an MP during 9 June 1983 to 9 April 1992. So he should already have been there. (maybe not for that meeting, but in general) Ideological reasons mean he abstains though.

Comment: @Will Any serious analysis, from independent journalists to security services to former members of the PIRA, have all found that PIRA and Sinn Fein are subordinate to the PAC, whose members are sourced from active PIRA volunteers with the paramilitary experience and social influence to be able to lead their members militarily and politically.  Do you have any evidence to doubt the MI5/PSNI 2015 report, which said: "PIRA members believe that the PAC [army council] oversees both PIRA and Sinn Féin with an overarching strategy."?  Or the historic relationship and order of things?

Comment: @Will There is absolutely no evidence to suggest anything else, like the idea that Sinn Fein leads PAC or PIRA.  So to suggest this is not straightforwards is incorrect.  This issue is an accepted fact, and local politics has been affected.  For example, after the 2015 report was published, [the DUP complained](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-northern-ireland-34589530) that the PAC should not still exist if they were truly dedicated to peace.

Comment: @inappropriateCode the characterisation in the answer implies subordinacy of Sinn Féin to the PIRA. That goes beyond the joint subordinacy to the PAC that you suggest is supported by the evidence. I'm sure there are meaningful contingents arguing strenuously for each case, and others arguing complete independence, irrespective of strength of evidence. The answer is right to focus on the nature of the conventional wisdom, not adjudicate on the facts, since the political significance of Corbyn's actions wouldn't really change even if the public view of Sinn Féin did diverge from reality.

Comment: @Will The answer does not present 'wisdom' in this case, it presents conjecture and false equivalence.  We can't just assume that because people argue both sides have a legitimate point.  I have presented evidence to refine the answer, if you have any evidence to the contrary, then please present it.  The point is relevant because either Corbyn's involvement in Irish politics is due to idiocy or malice.  If he never understood the reality of who he was sympathetic to, then it changes how seriously we consider his involvement.  I suspect he just waves an anti-imperialist flag.

Comment: @inappropriateCode Corbyn isn't purported to have participated in the operations or leadership of Sinn Féin, the PIRA or the PAC. He interacted politically with people who were members of some or all of them (admittedly or allegedly, in various combinations) so the perceived associations of those groups with terrorist acts *are* the relevant issue here, not what UK authorities may have known or claimed in 2015. It *is* the conjecture of the day on which he'd have had to base the question if he was at risk of collaborating with terrorists.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an account of his [historical involvement](https://www.channel4.com/news/factcheck/factcheck-corbyn-on-northern-ireland) with the NI peace process from Channel 4 factcheckers.

**TL;DR:** Corbyn was a professional muck-stirrer for most of his career. He took an unpopular position and stuck to it, and then acted in ways that seem designed to provoke outrage.

The summary is:

- He consistently campaigned for a peaceful resolution leading to a united Ireland. This included talking to republican politicians, some of whom had been convicted of terrorist offences. In one notorious incident two such people were invited to the House of Commons two weeks after the [Brighton bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brighton_hotel_bombing).
- He consistently refused to single out IRA bombers for condemnation, preferring to condemn all violence by all sides including the British Army. Seeing the IRA and the British Army as moral equivalents raised (and continues to raise) a lot of hackles.
- He was not involved in the real peace process between the UK government and the IRA, which was done via a secret back-channel. It is therefore unlikely that his involvement made any significant difference.

Comment: More accurately, he pays lip service to condemning all violence but is remarkably selective when choosing his examples of "violence" - not only in NI, but also in the Middle East and elsewhere in international politics.

Comment: The British army murdered unarmed protesters and colluded with loyalists (https://www.newstatesman.com/politics/northern-ireland/2019/03/how-british-forces-colluded-sectarian-violence-northern-ireland). Even if the British public feels that one is more morally upstanding than the other this is more tribalism than a reflection of reality

Comment: Did he regularly single out loyalists or the British army for condemnation? If he consistently condemned violence on all sides, that might be seen as a diplomatic tactic to defuse tribalism.